# Can I assign same LUIS subscription key to multiple Luis apps?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Can I assign same LUIS subscription key (generated from azure portal) to more than one LUIS application (On Luis.ai portal). I tried doing that and getting following error when I use the luis application in my bot:

*"This application cannot be accessed with the current subscription"*

Technically the luis.ai portal allowed me to assign the same key to multiple Luis apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming they are in the same region.

The authoring key in LUIS.ai is not the same thing as the endpoint LUIS subscription key in portal.azure.com. The authoring key allows you to author any LUIS app and the endpoint key allows you to query any LUIS endpoint. This doc should help understand keys learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/

Comment: Please expand your answer a bit to improve its quality.

Comment: the authoring key in LUIS.ai is not the same thing as the endpoint LUIS subscription key in portal.azure.com. The authoring key allows you to author any LUIS app and the endpoint key allows you to query any LUIS endpoint. This doc should help understand keys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#key-limits

Comment: Well, i understand the difference between the authoring and subscription key. My LUIS Apps are in the same region. With one LUIS account which mean associated with one authoring key I have multiple LUIS Applications. I tried using the same subscription key to all the luis app; it doesn't give me any error. With some more testing looks like there is no issues using the same subscription key/Endpoint key for multiple LUIS apps.